# Can i unregister NSNotificationCenter inside AppDelegate.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I'm registering for `Reachability notification` inside my `AppDelegate.m` by below piece of code.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
[reachability connectionRequired];
[reachability startNotifier];
```

**Can i unregister Reachability notifier inside my AppDelegate.m** ?

I am trying to unregister Reachability using below code.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put your NotificationCenter addObserv Code in to

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
[reachability connectionRequired];
[reachability startNotifier];

}
```

and remove it from:-

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: where should i use this? Inside AppDelegate.m or ViewController.m?

Comment: this above both method is Delegate method check in to your delegate.m you just need to put this code inside as a mention above